# Css transform in jquery

Tags: jquery, css-transforms

I needed to create a slider [like this](http://jemimahbarnett.com/) in blog section so I wrote script but I have a problem.

I want everything to show up in a loop. So if the last image / title goes to the first one.

In order for everything to work on the last slide I have to change the position of all previous slides so I do:

```
$('#news-slider-' + sliderId + ' .photos .photo').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)',
                    '-o-transform': 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)',
                    'transform': 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)'
                });
            }
        });
```

But it does not change before the next step. In the code I commented this as a problem.

My code is here:

```
jsfiddle.net/43gfzof4/
```

Comment: Why not use Slick plugin? No need to work on the JS so much. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I do not use plugin because I will need different animation for different items. For the time being we do not see it, but the titles will change as well.

Comment: The code in the Fiddle should be simplified. Anyways, I noticed that you only move them between -100% and +100% whereas you should move the images like numberOfPhotos*100% so that each follows the other (line 104 in the JS code in your Fiddle).

Also, why not use only one slider to make the code simpler, check the concept, and then use it in more sliders. Right now there is a lot of html/js code which would not be needed at this stage.